# on the airbus A320 does applying rudder and tiller sum up?

Tags: general-aviation, airbus-a320, airbus, airline-pilot, flight-engineer

on the airbus A320 while taxing, does applying rudder and tiller sum up the turn? if so where is it mentioned

Answer (score 5):

> on the airbus A320 while taxing, does applying rudder and tiller sum up the turn?

Yes. The pedal order is summed together with the commands from the two tillers. However, a pushbutton installed on each tiller allows the pilot to temporary exclude the rudder part of the input.

> if so where is it mentioned

Usually in the FCOM under "Landing Gear". See for example page 30 [here](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A319-320-321-Landing_Gear.pdf)

[image: Extract from link above:]

Comment: Thank you for replying, but page 30 does not mention tiller + rudder is added. It only tells tiller n f/o and capt side is algebraically added

Comment: @Deepak there is a diagram on the next page